# How many BSON ObjectIds can a mongodb array field save

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am planning to save huge number of ids for foreignkey ids in this array. So, I am just checking what would be the max number of BSON::ObjectIds I can save in the field array. Lets say for example

```
department_ids: [BSON::OBjectId('57cf6d6e8315292136000001'), BSON::OBjectId('57cf6d6e8315292136000002') ...... ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

16MB is big enough to hold really large amount of ObjectId, ObjectIds aren't that heavy, they are 12 bytes and when you divide it by 16MB you get well beyond 1 million.

But in case you still aren't assured, you can benefit by the flexible schema design of Mongo and create one follow-up document to hold further arrays and store the _id of that document in the concerned document with a field named as "followedBy" or something.

downside is you will have to execute a follow-up query (or maybe not).

Hope that helps.

Comment: By trial and error, holding a document with { _id: null, ids: [...] }, ids can have a maximum of *844,414* object ids. Tested with MongoDB v4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited 1st July 2021**

Since the document that contains the array **can not exceed 16 megabytes**, the number of objects in an array is limited.

The other answers explain how to calculate this.

[MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)

Comment: This is wrong, because the number(!) is limited by the 16 MB.So the maximum NUMBER of objects within an array is exactly:
`16 MB divided by the size of an Mongodb-object-id field (containing the "_id" plus the value itself)`.

Comment: sorry this is unrealistic, objectID size in  4 bytes so this in can't be unlimited....
flow the reference url : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid

Answer (score 0):

No such limit mentioned in documents of monogdb for it but a javascript array can have upto **2^32-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion elements**.

And **mongodb document could have upto 16MB.**

Comment: How does one account for the overhead bytes used for headers such as indicating that each element in the array is `ObjectId` and that the document itself is an array?

Comment: This is wrong, because the number(!) is limited by the 16 MB.So the maximum NUMBER of objects within an array is exactly:
`16 MB divided by the size of an Mongodb-object-id field (containing the "_id" plus the value itself)`.

Answer (score 0):

Every ObjectID uses 12 bytes, if the limit is 16 MB you could have approximately  1398101 objectsID in a array per document.

Maybe the [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) could help you,  or  you could use a [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-collections) collection.

If you could avoid the joins that would be the best solution on mongo.

Comment: How do you account for the bytes taken in BSON for indicating that the member of the array is `ObjectId` or that the document itself is an array? Based on [the spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), the document header would take 4 bytes, the array header 1 byte, and each entry in the array would take 1 byte for its header plus the 12 bytes. This leaves `(Math.pow(2, 24)-4-1)/(12+1)` or `1290554` if the document itself is just an array. But does MongoDB let you insert an array as a document?